# connect to a spring websocket with org.asynchttpclient in java desktop

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket

im trying to make an application who cominicates with a server made in spring-boot with websocket.

My server side configuration is the tutorial of spring-boot websocket

```
package ar.com.sourcesistemas.armController.websocket;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
}

}
```

This is my welcome controller:

```
package ar.com.sourcesistemas.armController;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

// inject via application.properties
@Value("${welcome.message:test}")
private String message = "Hello World";

@RequestMapping("/")
public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
    model.put("message", this.message);
    return "welcome";
}
```

}

and this is the broadcaster:

```
 package ar.com.sourcesistemas.armController;

import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import ar.com.sourcesistemas.armController.pruebas.Greeting;
import ar.com.sourcesistemas.armController.pruebas.HelloMessage;

@Controller
public class ArmController {

@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
}
```

}

to connect to this websocket im using org.asynchttpclient, and my code is this:

```
AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new DefaultAsyncHttpClient();
     String url = "ws://192.168.0.23:8080/gs-guide-websocket/app/topic/greetings";





    AsyncHttpClient c = new DefaultAsyncHttpClient();


    WebSocket websocket = c.prepareGet(url)
            .execute(new     WebSocketUpgradeHandler.Builder().addWebSocketListener(new     WebSocketTextListener() {

                public void onMessage(String message) {
                    System.out.println(message);

                }

                public void onOpen(WebSocket websocket) {
                    System.out.println("imp´rimo websocket");
                }

                public void onClose(WebSocket websocket) {
                    System.out.println("ni idea");
                }

                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                }
            }).build()).get();
```

Here i have 2 problems , the first one is :
when i run this program i have an error message in the server side it says "Origin cgeck enabled but transport 'greetings' does not support it".

The second one is:
To made a websocket you have 1 endpoint , in this case is "/gs-guide-websocket", and a broker you can subscribe. All data published in that broker will be broadcasted to all programs subscribed to it. In this case that channel to subscribe will be /app/toppic.
I cant figure out how to subscribe my java desktop application to this message broker.

MORE INFO
I can do this with jquery with this code :

```
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="sockjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="stomp.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var stompClient = null;



function connect() {
var socket = new SockJS('http://192.168.0.23:8080/gs-guide-websocket');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {

    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
    });
});
}

function showGreeting(message) {
    $("#greetings").append("<tr><td>" + message + "</td></tr>");
}

function disconnect() {
    if (stompClient != null) {
        stompClient.disconnect();
    }
    setConnected(false);
    console.log("Disconnected");
}


$( document ).ready(function() {

   connect();

});
```

but i cant reply this in a java desktop class.